# UK Visa: Proposed Civil Union

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I'm moving to Scotland 10/1/19 to live permanently with my partner who is a UK citizen.  After researching online, I found that I cannot be granted a visa as partner since we have not lived together for two years. I ended up completing a visa application partially based on the following from the UK.gov site: "If you want to live in the UK permanently, you must apply for a family of a settled person visa if your partner is any of the following: a British citizen..."  I finished the application, then read that I'd need to provide a marriage certificate...clearly the wrong application.  A note to HELP brought "you can apply for a family visa if you are married or you have been in a relationship for at least 2 years with your sponsor."  After more research I found the designation of the category I'm in: Proposed Civil Partners-SET02.  All I've been able to find are the regulations but not the application itself.  I've visited the Embassy's web site and found no help.  All I want is a link.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I think SET-02 is an obsolete form. If I’ve understood your situation correctly you have applied for the correct visa although perhaps you’ve misinterpreted some of the questions if it’s asking for a marriage certificate. You need to be able to prove that you are a proposed civil partner, will enter into a civil partnership within 6 months of arriving in the UK, and you meet the financial requirements https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse

Comment: Try looking for "fiance" instead - even if the form *says* fiance, it will almost certainly apply to proposed civil partner.

Comment: Incidentally, you do understand that "civil partner" requires your partner to be the same sex as you?  It is functionally equivalent to marriage, and was introduced rather than annoy traditionalists opposed to gay marriage.  It is **not** equivalent to a French *pacte civil de solidarité*.

Comment: @Martin Bonner There is no application form, it’s an online application system via the gov.uk page I linked to above - the OP just needs to scroll down to find the link to the online application https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/apply-visa-type/appendixfm

Comment: Thanks, Traveller. I used the link you sent yesterday and I believe it was the same one I'd originally completed, now under Appendix FM Partner.  I'm still leery since one of the documents required is "Proof that Cindy... and John...plan on marrying within six months."  How am I supposed to prove we're planning a civil union we haven't even scheduled yet?  Regardless, I hope this is the correct form because I've paid a small fortune for it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MartinBonner that is no longer correct. [In June 2018, the Supreme Court ruled that allowing only same-sex couples to enter a civil partnership is incompatible with the European Convention on Human Rights. The UK Government later pledged to allow opposite-sex couples in England and Wales to enter into civil partnerships, and legislation enabling this passed the Parliament in March 2019 and went into effect on 26 May 2019.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_partnership_in_the_United_Kingdom)

Comment: @Cindy AFAIK, you can’t give notice to marry unless you have the appropriate visa. You could perhaps show eg you’d booked a venue, or have an appointment to give notice for the ceremony https://www.gov.uk/get-married-in-england-or-wales

Comment: Phoog, unfortunately the last line of that info from Wikipedia is "The Secretary of State is required to issue regulations allowing opposite-sex civil partnerships by 31 December 2019."  Thanks for the shot.